# how to create a map from a maplist with selected key and value in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of maps that contains bank data and now creating a chart requires key and value.

```
void main() {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> maplist = [
        {
            'Bank': 'HDFC',
            'Balance': 10900.00,
            'Transactions': []
        },
        {
            'Bank': 'AXIS',
            'Balance': 5900.00,
            'Transactions': []
        },
        {
            'Bank': 'UCO',
            'Balance': 4200.00,
            'Transactions': []
        },
        {
            'Bank': 'ICICI',
            'Balance': 2300.00,
            'Transactions': []
        },
        {
            'Bank': 'KOTAK',
            'Balance': 1200.00,
            'Transactions': []
        },
    ];
    Map<String, double> chartData = {};
}
```

I want the following result in `chartData`

```
{
  'HDFC':10900, 'AXIS':5900,'UCO':4200,'OTHERS':3500}
}
```

it should take the first 3 banks and the fourth key `OTHERS` should be the present sum of all other bank's balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not mention what to do when maplist length is less than 4...

here i have created code including condiontion on length..if length is less than 3..OTHER is not calculated...

```
Map<String, dynamic> getChartData(List<Map<String, dynamic>> maplist) {
  Map<String, double> chartData = {};

  if (maplist.length > 3) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
      chartData[maplist[x]['Bank']] = maplist[x]['Balance'];
    }
    //for calculating sum of all OTHER account
    chartData['Others'] = maplist.sublist(3).fold(
        0, (previousValue, element) => previousValue + element["Balance"]);
  } else {
    //when key value pair are less than three...no calculation for OTHER
    for (int x = 0; x < maplist.length; x++) {
      chartData[maplist[x]['Bank']] = maplist[x]['Balance'];
    }
  }
  return chartData;
}

void main() {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> maplist = [
    {'Bank': 'HDFC', 'Balance': 10900.00, 'Transactions': []},
    {'Bank': 'AXIS', 'Balance': 5900.00, 'Transactions': []},
    {'Bank': 'UCO', 'Balance': 4200.00, 'Transactions': []},
    {'Bank': 'ICICI', 'Balance': 2300.00, 'Transactions': []},
    {'Bank': 'KOTAK', 'Balance': 1200.00, 'Transactions': []},
  ];

  print(getChartData(maplist));
}
```

I have checked this code...Working the way you want...

Answer (score 1):

In the below, i have created a function convertToMap, which takes the List and generates the map.

```
Map<String, double> convertToMap(List<Map<String, dynamic>> maplist) {
  if (maplist.length <= 3) {
    return {for (var e in maplist) e['Bank']: e['Balance']};
  }

  var firstThree = maplist.take(3).fold<Map<String, double>>(
    {},
    (acc, curr) => acc..[curr['Bank']] = curr['Balance'],
  );

  var othersSum =
      maplist.skip(3).fold(0.0, (sum, curr) => sum + curr['Balance']);

  return {...firstThree, 'OTHERS': othersSum};
}
```

To use the function, try the below.

```
Map<String, double> chartData = convertToMap(maplist);
```

You could also try another approach, using loops and conditionals.

```
Map<String, double> convertToMap(List<Map<String, dynamic>> maplist) {
  Map<String, double> resultMap = {};

  double othersSum = 0.0;

  for (int i = 0; i < maplist.length; i++) {
    if (i < 3) {
      resultMap[maplist[i]['Bank']] = maplist[i]['Balance'];
    } else {
      othersSum += maplist[i]['Balance'];
    }
  }

  if (othersSum > 0) {
    resultMap['OTHERS'] = othersSum;
  }

  return resultMap;
}
```

In the above, we loop through the maplist, check the index to decide how to process the current item(set the key to 'Bank' and the value to 'Balance'), and then builds the result map.

Then use the function like the below:

```
Map<String, double> chartData = convertToMap(maplist);
```

Comment: what about last key others and its value?

Comment: Corrected the response. Was an oversight.

Comment: Hope this works for you @IMemon

Comment: Thanks...right now upvoting ur answer as i feel there must be another easy to solve...bit hard to understand..need time to study your code...Thanks

Comment: Alright. Added a second approach and some explanation, if that helps.

Comment: Ur code already worked but as i said..looking for other options..and pls upvote if it can helpful for others

Answer (score 0):

just use this function for that:

```
Map<String, double> mapTpChartData(
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> maplist, {
  List<String>? banks,
}) {
  Map<String, double> chartData = {};
  for (var map in maplist) {
    final bankName = map['Bank'];
    if (banks != null && !banks.contains(bankName)) {
      chartData['OTHERS'] = (chartData['OTHERS'] ?? 0) + map['Balance'];
    } else {
      chartData[bankName] = map['Balance'];
    }
  }
  return chartData;
}
```

Full example is:

```
void main() {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> maplist = [
    {'Bank': 'HDFC', 'Balance': 10900.00, 'Transactions': []},
    {'Bank': 'AXIS', 'Balance': 5900.00, 'Transactions': []},
    {'Bank': 'UCO', 'Balance': 4200.00, 'Transactions': []},
    {'Bank': 'ICICI', 'Balance': 2300.00, 'Transactions': []},
    {'Bank': 'KOTAK', 'Balance': 1200.00, 'Transactions': []},
  ];

  Map<String, double> chartData = mapTpChartData(maplist, banks: [
    'HDFC',
    'AXIS',
    'UCD',
  ]);

  print(chartData);
  // {HDFC: 10900.0, AXIS: 5900.0, OTHERS: 7700.0}
}

Map<String, double> mapTpChartData(
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> maplist, {
  List<String>? banks,
}) {
  Map<String, double> chartData = {};
  for (var map in maplist) {
    final bankName = map['Bank'];
    if (banks != null && !banks.contains(bankName)) {
      chartData['OTHERS'] = (chartData['OTHERS'] ?? 0) + map['Balance'];
    } else {
      chartData[bankName] = map['Balance'];
    }
  }
  return chartData;
}
```

Comment: but i want to store sum of all remaining banks to others's value

Comment: @IMemon, I updated the answer, if you want, you can use updated option.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you required case.

```
Map<String, double> chartData = {
  maplist[0]["Bank"]: maplist[0]["Balance"],
  maplist[1]["Bank"]: maplist[1]["Balance"],
  maplist[2]["Bank"]: maplist[2]["Balance"],
  "OTHERS": maplist
      .sublist(3)
      .fold(0, (previousValue, element) => previousValue + element["Balance"]),
};
```

We are getting first 3 elements and for others we are doing summation of all balances.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: can u pls check this...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76962693/failing-to-set-value-while-using-providers-constructor-in-flutter